# Sql XML return check multiple nodes for a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

Here is my xml

```
  <Configuration>
    <Name>EscalatedSubscribers</Name>
    <Role>Configuration</Role>
    <UISettings>
      <Control>
       <Name>SubscriberSelector</Name>
       <Type>Configuration</Type>
       <DisplayItem>Workspaces</DisplayItem>
      </Control>
    </UISettings>
    <Values>
     <Required>
      <Name Type="WS">ganderson</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">mhoffmann</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">lmcswain</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">jbranham</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">gsimpson</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">jbennett</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">bdrum</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">mtrott</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">acannon</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">dgantt</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">evalone</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">flyons</Name>
      <Name Type="WS">saheavner</Name>
    </Required>
   </Values>
  </Configuration>
```

My dataset has an ID, and a name, and the xml field. The goal is to query into the xml for every name, and if the user 'ganderson' is a value of the name node, return that name node.

```
 SELECT p.Tag.query('(/Configuration/Values/Required/*)')
```

return the fulle required node and i am checking if the node is LIKE '%ganderson%'

```
 SELECT p.Tag.value('(/Configuration/Values/Required[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max) )
```

returns the first user, which is ganderson, but just because i got lucky. There has to be a more effecient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check if this name exists in xml column by variable or from column.

First I created table and added some data (used same xml you wrote for xmlData column):

```
DECLARE @xmlTable TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(200), xmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @xmlTable SELECT 1, 'evalone', <xmlData>
INSERT INTO @xmlTable SELECT 2, 'lmcswain', <xmlData>
INSERT INTO @xmlTable SELECT 3, '22222', <xmlData>
```

then you can find Name from table in xmlData column like this:

```
SELECT xmldata.query('(/Configuration/Values/Required/Name[text()=sql:column("name")])')
FROM @xmlTable
WHERE xmldata.exist('/Configuration/Values/Required/Name[text()=sql:column("name")]') = 1
```

Result:

```
<Name Type="WS">evalone</Name>
<Name Type="WS">lmcswain</Name>
```

Or you can put some text to search from variable:

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(200) = 'jbranham';

SELECT xmldata.query('(/Configuration/Values/Required/Name[text()=sql:variable("@id")])')
FROM @xmlTable
WHERE xmldata.exist('/Configuration/Values/Required/Name[text()=sql:variable("@id")]') = 1
```

Results:

```
<Name Type="WS">jbranham</Name>
<Name Type="WS">jbranham</Name>
<Name Type="WS">jbranham</Name>
```

first with `exists` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx)) I check, if searched `text()` exists in `Name` node and then using `query` get that node.

Comment: I guess my question is, where you have text()=sql:variable() what other options do i have. im trying to pull in a column fromm a different table.

Comment: so as you can see you can also use `sql:column("name")`